# How to add a row to the result of a SQL query with INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, union, inner-join

In times past, when I need to add a row to the result of a SQL statement, I write a statement like this:

```
SELECT colA, colB FROM my_table   
UNION  
SELECT 'foo' AS colA, 'bar' as colB;
```

However, suppose I've written the following SQL:

```
SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t2.colC FROM my_table t1 INNER JOIN my_other_table t2
```

How can I add my extra row to my_table when it is INNER JOINed to another table like this?

**Update**:  Wow, I just goofed.  It's almost going-home time.  I forgot my where clause!

```
SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t2.colC
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN my_other_table t2
  ON t1.colB = t2.colC
```

Comment: The `UNION` only requires the dimensions and types be the same, column names are disregarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    (t1.colA, t1.colB FROM my_table 
     UNION 
     SELECT 'foo' AS colA, 'bar' as colB) as t1 
INNER JOIN 
    my_other_table t2 ON . . .
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Please note that colA and colB are columns in my_table, but colC is a column in my_other_table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t2.colC FROM my_table t1 INNER JOIN my_other_table t2
UNION
SELECT 'foo' as colA, 'bar' as colB, 'baz' as colC
```

Comment: Might be fine, although the UNION (I assume he/she wants UNION ALL) will result in the final row always being added; in other words, the join will not prevent it from being included.

Comment: Actually, that has nothing to do with UNION vs. UNION ALL--disregard all but my last clause.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `mytable` in your second query with `(SELECT ...)`, the whole first query (in parenthesis):

```
SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t2.colC
FROM 
(   SELECT colA, colB
    FROM my_table
  UNION  
    SELECT 'foo' AS colA, 'bar' as colB
) AS t1
INNER JOIN my_other_table t2
  ON t1.colB = t2.colC     
;
```